# How to create an anonymous array of object references

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference

I've inherited some code I'd like to DRY up into to 2 loops.

The outer loop iterates over checkBoxeList object.
The inner loop checks all the boxes.

```
CheckBoxList[] DefaultLists = { ScanDefaultTasks, BehDefaultTasks,MEGDefaultTasks,DefaultQuestionnaires };
for (int i = 0; i < DefaultLists.Count (); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < DefaultLists[i].Items.Count; j++)
    {
        DefaultLists[i].Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

How could `DefaultList` be built such that it stores references to each of the checkBoxList objects?

How should these references be called?

It looks like one solution is to build a ["box" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900383/c-array-of-references-pointers-to-a-number-of-integers). This pattern occurs a few times, in most places duplicating greater lengths of redundant code. Building a class for each instance seems like overkill.

---

The original looks like

```
for (int i = 0; i < ScanDefaultTasks.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ScanDefaultTasks.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
for (int i = 0; i < BehDefaultTasks.Items.Count; i++)
{
    BehDefaultTasks.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
for (int i = 0; i < MEGDefaultTasks.Items.Count; i++)
{
    MEGDefaultTasks.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
for (int i = 0; i < DefaultQuestionnaires.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DefaultQuestionnaires.Items[i].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but what's wrong with `var DefaultLists = new List<CheckBoxList>(){ ScanDefaultTasks, BehDefaultTasks,MEGDefaultTasks,DefaultQuestionnaires };`?

Comment: @KonradKokosa like the CheckBoxList[] construction, the page hangs until timeout. Why, I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultLists is an array that stores references to the contained CheckBoxLists. So I do not see a problem there. The only problem I can spot in your sample is that you use `i` where you should use `j` in the inner loop:

```
CheckBoxList[] DefaultLists = { ScanDefaultTasks, BehDefaultTasks,MEGDefaultTasks,DefaultQuestionnaires };
for (int i = 0; i < DefaultLists.Count (); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < DefaultLists[i].Items.Count; j++)
    {
        DefaultLists[i].Items[j].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

I've changed the second `i` to a `j` in this line:

```
DefaultLists[i].Items[j].Selected = true;
```

In order to simplify things a bit, you could also use for each for the loops:

```
CheckBoxList[] DefaultLists = { ScanDefaultTasks, BehDefaultTasks,MEGDefaultTasks,DefaultQuestionnaires };
foreach(var cbl in DefaultLists)
    foreach(var item in cbl.Items)
        item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: also needed to change an i->j inside the for loop conditional. given that I can't distinguish between the indexes I choose, foreach seems like a much better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in new CheckBoxList[]{
                             ScanDefaultTasks, 
                             BehDefaultTasks,
                             MEGDefaultTasks,
                             DefaultQuestionnaires}
                      .SelectMany(l => l.Items))
  item.Selected = true;
```