# How to create a dynamic array of int pointers in c#?

Tags: c#

I want something like `std::vector<int*> v` from C++, but in C#.

I tried `List<int*> v`, but the compiler said that

> CS0306  C# The type may not be used as a type argument

I want to put `int` variables and change it through the array something like that in C++

```cpp
std::vector<int*> v;
int a = 2;
v.push_back(&a);
v[0] = 4; // (a == 4) true
```

Comment: I would still use a List but when passing to other libraries use v.ToArray()

Comment: This is almost always the wrong thing to do in C#. It sounds like you are asking an "XY" question. That is a question where you have some wrong idea about how to solve a problem, and you're asking a question about the wrong idea instead of the real problem. What's the real problem?

Comment: "Pointer to integer local variable" would be pair of delegates like `var changer = new { get = (Func<int> )(()=>a),  set = (Action<int>)(newValue => a = newValue) };
changer.set(10);`... but as @EricLippert said you likely have much better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Right, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900383/c-array-of-references-pointers-to-a-number-of-integers/4900470#4900470 for a discussion of this technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off let me say very clearly: **solving problems in C# using the same low-level pointer techniques as you would in C++ is almost always the wrong thing to do**.  There is usually a higher-level, safer technique you can use.  What you're doing here is called an "XY question" -- you have a wrong idea about how to solve a problem, and you're asking a question about the wrong idea, instead of asking how to solve the real problem; please edit the question to say what the real problem is.

To answer your question that was asked: to make a "dynamic array" of pointers in C# you must make a `List<IntPtr>` which is a list of "integers that are the same size as a pointer".  **Do not fall into the trap of believing that `IntPtr` means pointer to integer**.  An `IntPtr` is an *integer that is the same size as a pointer*.

You can then convert your `int*`s to `IntPtr` and store them in the list, and then convert them back again when you're done, but again, *this is almost always the wrong thing to do*, and if you do so then you are responsible for understanding **everything** about the .NET memory management system and how it works, because **you are turning off the safety system that protects memory integrity**.

Do you believe that you understand **everything** about how memory management works in C#? If not, then **do not use pointer types in C#**.  I have been developing code in C# since 2001 and I have never used pointer types for anything in production code. You don't need them, and if you think you need them, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I close this question and ask an origin question

Comment: I think you've mixed order of words "code in C#" shouldn't it be "C# in code" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the lack of having a pointer to a value type by creating a wrapper to the value like that:

```
static void Test()
{
  var v = new List<EmbeddedInt>();
  var a = new EmbeddedInt(2);
  v.Add(a);
  v[0].Value = 4;
  Console.WriteLine(a);  // Display 4
}

public class EmbeddedInt
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Value.ToString();
  }
  public EmbeddedInt(int value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
}
```

This is a simple example here.

To be able to compute on the value without using `a + 2` instead of `a.Value + 2` you may implement some methods like operators.

The only thing you can't do is overloading the assignment operator...

Take a look at this:

[Define assigment operator that change the value of some "this" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189427/define-assigment-operator-that-change-the-value-of-some-this-in-c-sharp/58189654#58189654)